# Running Mono applications on Windows without typing "mono filename.exe"?

Tags: c#, windows, mono

I've just started to learn how to code in C# and my lecturer ask me to use Mono to compile
but I realized that everytime I want to run the program, I need to open cmd.exe and type "mono filename.exe"

Is there a way to make the program run without typing it (for example by double clicking)?
Thanks

Comment: What happens when you double-click it? I'm pretty sure the Mono linker should output PE executables (runnable as-is on Windows). See http://mono-project.com/Using_Mono_on_Windows.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi this is what happens when I double click my program called "center.exe" --> http://prntscr.com/31xk5n

Comment: Looks like a bitness problem. Maybe some of the assemblies you reference target x86 but your application targets x64, or the other way around. I would double-check that.

Comment: so is there any solution to solve this "bitness" problem? I'm still newbie here :(

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have enough information to suggest an appropriate solution. Maybe someone else has experienced the same problem first hand and will step up to answer.

Comment: What if you ngen it? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: http://mono-project.com/Guide:Running_Mono_Applications

Comment: I'm not using Visual Studio to code this.. so how to ngen it?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is that the application is specifically a GTK app. When you install Mono it will come with the GTK# runtime but this is not installed in the .NET GAC. You can fix this numerous ways and the quickest test is by marking all the GTK references in the project with "Local copy" so they will be copied to the application folder.

From the project file (`**<Private>True</Private>**`):

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="gtk-sharp, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
```

If you prefer to use IDE, you can download MonoDevelop here: http://monodevelop.com/

Comment: Yes I'm building using Gtk.. how to mark the option? I'm using notepad++ and command prompt, not using VS